# How to customize the top-left text label on the background windows of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

By default, Inno Setup use the `AppName` as text source for the top-left text label displayed in the fullscreen background when we use `WindowVisible`. I would like also to print the `Publisher` and the `Version`.

I found many help topics to put an image as background but nothing to change the displayed text. Is there a way to do it, without modifying the `[Setup] AppName` parameter?

```
#define MyAppName "MyAppName"
#define MyAppVer "4.1"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVer}
AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVer}
WindowVisible=True
```

[image: Screenshot of Innosetup with WindowVisible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible. There's no "label" control for the application name text. The name is drawn on the window directly.

Maybe you can obscure the built-in label behind some panel and put your own label on top of it.

---

Though, why are you even using `WindowVisible`? It's pretty old-school and against Microsoft UI guidelines. You better abandon that.